# How to set the InitialShowDelay of a style for a tooltip?

Tags: wpf, wpf-style

I am trying to set the delay of a style for a tooltip. For that, I am using a dependency property.

This is style:

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip" x:Key="ToolTipDefaultStyle">
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="{Binding PlacementTarget.(ap:ToolTipAttachedProperty.InitialShowDelay), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}}"/>
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="{Binding PlacementTarget.(ap:ToolTipAttachedProperty.ShowDuration), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}}"/>
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlacementTarget.(ap:ToolTipAttachedProperty.Texto), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}}"  MaxWidth="400" TextWrapping='Wrap' />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is the view:

```
<StackPanel Name="spTiposIva" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0"
            ap:ToolTipAttachedProperty.Texto="{Binding TiposIvaTooltip}"
            ap:ToolTipAttachedProperty.InitialShowDelay="10000"
            ap:ToolTipAttachedProperty.ShowDuration="{StaticResource TooltipDisplayTime}">
    <StackPanel.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource ToolTipDefaultStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel.ToolTip>
</StackPanel>
```

The text is correctly shown, but the intial show delay is the default value, it doesn't delay 10 seconds.

How could I set the delay?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other properties, e.g. `ShowOnDisabled` do not work either. That is because you set the attached `ToolTipService` properties on `ToolTip` itself or in a style targeting it. Instead, you have to set these properties on the control that the tool tip is associated with, **not the tool tip itself**.

It will work, if you directly attach them to the `StackPanel` or in a style for it, for example:

```
<StackPanel Name="spTiposIva" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0"
            ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
            ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="10000"
            ToolTipService.ShowDuration="{StaticResource TooltipDisplayTime}"
            ToolTip="Binding TiposIvaTooltip">
   <!-- ...your content. -->
</StackPanel>
```

You could just go on directly attaching the tool tip service properties to controls. You do not need to create your own attached properties for the same thing that `ToolTipService` already provides. It seems like a level of indirection, but you can do it. Below, you find examples for styles that work.

In your example above, you can split your `ToolTip` style and create a style for `StackPanel`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}" x:Key="StackPanelDefaultStyle">
   <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="true"/>
   <Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="{Binding (ap:ToolTipAttachedProperty.InitialShowDelay), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
   <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="{Binding (ap:ToolTipAttachedProperty.ShowDuration), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</Style>
```

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip" x:Key="ToolTipDefaultStyle">
   <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
      <Setter.Value>
         <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlacementTarget.(ap:ToolTipAttachedProperty.Texto), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}}"  MaxWidth="400" TextWrapping='Wrap' />
            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Another approach could be to create a base style that other control styles are based on. It would be the same style as for `StackPanel`, but with `FrameworkElement` as target type to apply to all controls.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}" x:Key="FrameworkElementDefaultStyle">
```